# what is the error in my code that cause this sentence to pop up 'Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression'?

Tags: reactjs

I'm getting an error in my code that says

> 'Line 35:  Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an
>   expression'

Line 35 is `this.props.handleState(state),`

not sure how to resolve it

I created an arrow function called `handleStep` that has an `if` statement along with props.

```
class HostWizard extends Component {
    constructor(){
        super()
        this.state = {
            city: '',
            state: '',
            zipcode: '',
            image: '',
            Price: '',
            name:'',
            telephoneNumber: '',
            streetAddress: '',
            stayType: ''
        }
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        console.log('hello')
    }

    handleChange =(e)=> {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.setState({[e.target.name]: e.target.value})
    }

    handleStep = (e) => {        
        if(e = '') {
            alert('Please fill out all information')
        } else {
            let { city, state, zipcode, image, price, name, 
            telephoneNumber, streetAddress, stayType} = this.state
            this.props.handleState(state),
            this.props.handleCity(city),
            this.props.handleZipcode(zipcode),
            this.props.handleImage(image),
            this.props.handlePrice(price),
            this.props.handleName(name),
            this.props.handleTelephoneNumber(telephoneNumber),
            this.props.handleStreetAddress(streetAddress),
            this.props.handleStayType(stayType) }
    }



    render(){
        return(
            <div>

            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default HostWizard
```

**I expect the arrow function to work**

Answer (score 0):

Change your constructor as follows

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    console.log(this.props)
    this.state = {
            city: '',
            state: '',
            zipcode: '',
            image: '',
            Price: '',
            name:'',
            telephoneNumber: '',
            streetAddress: '',
            stayType: ''
        }
}
```